# How to get all files that were added/modified during installation?

Tags: windows, installation

When I install a program I need to know what files were added/modified, which registry was modified. Can someone suggest a program that does this or maybe a code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this tool makes exactly what you need: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows
>   real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity. It
>   combines the features of two legacy Sysinternals utilities, Filemon
>   and Regmon, and adds an extensive list of enhancements including rich
>   and non-destructive filtering, comprehensive event properties such
>   session IDs and user names, reliable process information, full thread
>   stacks with integrated symbol support for each operation, simultaneous
>   logging to a file, and much more. Its uniquely powerful features will
>   make Process Monitor a core utility in your system troubleshooting and
>   malware hunting toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Systracer perfectly do what you want:

> SysTracer is a system utility tool that can scan and analyze your
>   computer to find changed (added, modified or deleted) data into
>   registry and files.

There is both a free and a paid versions.

http://www.blueproject.ro/systracer